# dc.js piechart legend: display only top 5

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am generating a piechart (doughnut chart to be precise) which has around 50 items, but the top 5 of them accounts for 95% of the chart. When I display the legend info, its overlapping the chart, since there are many legend items. I was wondering if there is an option to just limit the legend display to top 5 items.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#legend

I do not see any option to limit the legend display to say top 5 or top 10.

Comment: I guess it is assumed that you would cap the pie chart itself, rather than just excluding the tiny ones from the legend.

Comment: I have a dc.dataTable which displays the items as a tabular format. I cannot cap the pie chart itself, since that would remove entries from my dataTable.

Comment: The capping should only affect the way the data is displayed in the piechart; it should not affect any other chart.

Comment: By capping, did you mean using the .data() callback?

Comment: No, I mean using the [capped mixin](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#cap-mixin) which the pie chart inherits from.  It simply takes the smallest bins and puts them together into an "Others" bin.  It won't affect other charts.  See the [pie example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/pie.html).

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That works for my case :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always modify the dc.js library itself where you can do the following in the legend mixin:

```
dc.legend = function () {
...
//START MODIFICATION
var _maxItems;
_legend.maxItems = function(maxItems) {
    _maxItems = maxItems;
    return _legend;
};
//END MODIFICATION
...
_legend.render = function () {
    _parent.svg().select('g.dc-legend').remove();
    _g = _parent.svg().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'dc-legend')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + _x + ',' + _y + ')');
    var legendables = _parent.legendables();

    //START MODIFICATION
    if (_maxItems) {
        legendables = legendables.slice(0, _maxItems);
    }
    //END MODIFICATION
...
}
```